# Connection refused in Hbase Shell while Connecting HBase to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to connect my HBase to HDFS. I have my hdfs namenode(bin/hdfs namenode) and datnode(/bin/hdfs datanode) running. I can also start my Hbase (sudo ./bin/start-hbase.sh) and local region servers (sudo ./bin/local-regionservers.sh start 1 2). But when I try to execute a command from Hbase shell it gives the following error:

```
cis655stu@cis655stu-VirtualBox:/teaching/14f-cis655/proj-dtracing/hbase/hbase-0.99.0-SNAPSHOT$ ./bin/hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.99.0-SNAPSHOT, rUnknown, Sat Aug  9 08:59:57 EDT 2014

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                    
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/teaching/14f-cis655/proj-dtracing/hbase/hbase-0.99.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/teaching/14f-cis655/proj-dtracing/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2015-01-19 13:33:07,179 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

ERROR: Connection refused

Here is some help for this command:
List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:

  hbase> list
  hbase> list 'abc.*'
  hbase> list 'ns:abc.*'
  hbase> list 'ns:.*'
```

Below are my configuration files for HBase and Hadoop:

HBase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>

    <!--for psuedo-distributed execution-->
    <property>
      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.master.wait.on.regionservers.mintostart</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
      <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/teaching/14f-cis655/tmp/zk-deploy</value>
      </property>

    <!--for enabling collection of traces
    -->
    <property>
      <name>hbase.trace.spanreceiver.classes</name>
      <value>org.htrace.impl.LocalFileSpanReceiver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.local-file-span-receiver.path</name>
      <value>/teaching/14f-cis655/tmp/server-htrace.out</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

Hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/teaching/14f-cis655/proj-dtracing/hadoop-2.6.0/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/teaching/14f-cis655/proj-dtracing/hadoop-2.6.0/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>hadoop.trace.spanreceiver.classes</name>
    <value>org.htrace.impl.LocalFileSpanReceiver</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.local-file-span-receiver.path</name>
    <value>/teaching/14f-cis655/proj-dtracing/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/htrace.out</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If yes, could you please share the solution.

Comment: Try to delete the directory in which zookeeper writes it's data. Then restart     your HBase

Comment: In my case the directory is /teaching/14f-cis655/tmp/zk-deploy

Answer (score 3):

Please check does you HDFS is available from shell:

```
  $ hdfs dfs -ls /hbase
```

Also make sure that you've all environment variables in **hdfs-env.sh** file:

```
HADOOP_CONF_LIB_NATIVE_DIR="/hadoop/lib/native"
HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/hadoop/lib"
HADOOP_HOME=/hadoop
YARN_HOME=/hadoop
HBASE_HOME=/hbase
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/hadoop
HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Do you run Hadoop and HBase using the same OS user? If you use separate users, please check if HBase user is allowed to access HDFS.

Make sure that you have a copy of **hdfs-site.xml** and **core-stie.xml** (or symlink) files in **${HBASE_HOME}/conf** directory.

Also **fs.default.name** option is deprecated for YARN (but it must still work), you must consider using **fs.defaultFS** instead.

Do you use Zookeeper? Because you've specified **hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir** option, but there is no **hbase.zookeeper.quorum** there, and other significant options. Please read http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#zookeeper for more information.

Please add next option to **hdfs-site.xml** to make HBase work correctly (replace **$HBASE_USER** variable by your system user, which is used to run HBase):

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.$HBASE_USER.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.$HBASE_USER.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.support.append</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Yes, so the issue was the zookeeper quorum process was not running. It was fixed after I deleted deleted the directory in which HBase holds it's temporary data. It works fine now.